# Mina: Can't deploy anymore: RVM with current Ruby is installed on server, but too old ruby version is used while deploying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment

After over a year of not touching a Rails app, I updated all gems and tried to deploy again.

I get this error:

```
       Installing sassc 2.0.1 with native extensions

       Gem::InstallError: sassc requires Ruby version >= 2.3.3.
       Using rb-inotify 0.10.0
       Using mime-types 3.2.2
       Using coffee-script 2.4.1
       Using compass-core 1.0.3
       Using compass-import-once 1.0.5
       Using sdoc 1.0.0
       Using slim 4.0.1
       Using validates_timeliness 4.1.1
       Using validates_email_format_of 1.6.3
       Using activesupport 5.2.3
       Using loofah 2.2.3
       Using axlsx 2.1.0.pre from https://github.com/randym/axlsx.git (at c8ac844@c8ac844)
       Installing mobility 0.8.7

       Gem::InstallError: mobility requires Ruby version >= 2.3.7.
       Using css_parser 1.7.0
       An error occurred while installing sassc (2.0.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
       Make sure that `gem install sassc -v '2.0.1'` succeeds before bundling.
 !     ERROR: Deploy failed.
-----> Cleaning up build
       Unlinking current
       OK
       Connection to XXX closed.

 !     Run Error
```

So the Ruby version used by Mina is too old (`< 2.3.7`).

Interestingly, when I log into the server, I see that RVM has installed Ruby `2.4.1`:

```
$ rvm list

rvm rubies

   ruby-2.2.5 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.3.1 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.4.1 [ x86_64 ]
```

After taking a closer look at Mina's output, I see:

```
Warning: the running version of Bundler is older than the version that created the lockfile. We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
```

I wonder which Ruby version Mina is using? And how can I tell it to use the same version that the Rails-app uses on the server?

I'm in contact with the server support, and they are asking:

> How does mina concretely work? Is this done locally or remotely on our system?

I don't know what to answer, I'm a "simple" Rails programmer with not much experience in deploying apps. It used to work perfectly a year ago, now it doesn't do anymore.

Thanks for any help.